# Constructing a function based on position, velocity, and acceleration.

Tags: functions, derivatives, roots

I'm trying to find a function $f$ that simulates the motion of a particle that conforms to the following constraints.

1. The particle begins at position 0 and moves to 1.
2. The velocity is 0 at the start and end of the motion.
3. The particle accelerates at a constant rate until an inflection point and then decelerates at a constant rate.

Because $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$, and $f''(0)=0$, I start with $x^3$ and then find a function $g$ that satisfies the other conditions. First take the derivatives.

$$f(x)=x^3g(x)$$

$$f'(x)=3x^2g(x)+x^3g'(x)$$

$$f''(x)=6xg(x)+6x^2g'(x)+x^3g''(x)$$

Then solve for the values of $g$ that correspond to the points I want.

$$f'(1)=0 \Rightarrow 3g(1)+g'(1)=0 \Rightarrow g'(1)=-3$$

$$f''(1)=0 \Rightarrow 6g(1)+6g'(1)+g''(1) \Rightarrow g''(1)=12$$

Then, choosing $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, solve for the constants.

$$g''(1)=12 \Rightarrow 2a=12 \Rightarrow a=6$$

$$g'(1)=-3 \Rightarrow 2a+b=-3 \Rightarrow b=-15$$

$$g(1)=1 \Rightarrow a+b+c=1 \Rightarrow c=10$$

This gives $f(x)=x^3(6x^2-15x+10)=6x^5-15x^4+10x^3$. This function works when the inflection point is at $x=0.5$.

What I want is a way to find a function for any inflection point in $(0,1)$. I'm not sure how to generalize this process or expand on it to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of the function should be the time t. It can be assumed that the particle reaches the point 1 at time T which is a parameter. Now we have
$x(0)=0 ;\; x(T)=1;\; \dot x(0)=0;\; \dot x(T)=0\;.$ Furthermore, because of symmetry, we have $\ddot x(t)=a$ on $0 \le t \lt T/2$ and $\ddot x(t)=-a$ on $T/2 \le t \le T.$ The intervals $0 \le t \lt T/2$ and $T/2 \le t \le T$ can now be treated separately. Integration in the first interval gives: $\dot x=at+v_0\;$ where $v_0=0$ because of $\dot x(0)=0$. Another integration gives $x(t)=\frac{a}{2}t^2+x_0$ where $x_0=0$ because of $x(0)=0$. The second interval can be treated analogously to find the solution $x(t)=-\frac{a}{2}t^2+aTt+1-\frac{a}{2}T^2$. (It is a little more laborious to determine the constants $x_1$ and $v_1$ here.) By derivation and inserting the given values at time 0 and T it can be checked that the required conditions are fullfilled. If the inflection point is not at $T/2$, replace $T/2$ by a parameter value, say $T_i$, and use different accelerations, e.g. $a_1;\;-a_2$, in both intervals.